# No matching distribution found for antlr-python-runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine, antlr

```
pip install google_appengine
Collecting google-appengine
  Using cached google-appengine-1.5.1.tar.gz
Collecting pyyaml (from google-appengine)
  Using cached PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz
Collecting webob==0.9 (from google-appengine)
  Using cached WebOb-0.9.tar.gz
Collecting ipaddr (from google-appengine)
  Using cached ipaddr-2.1.11.tar.gz
Collecting antlr-python-runtime (from google-appengine)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement antlr-python-runtime (from google-appengine) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for antlr-python-runtime (from google-appengine)
```

Pip shows it is available but doesn't install it:

```
pip search antlr
antlr4-python-alt          - Alternative Python runtime for ANTLR 4
antlr_python_runtime       - Runtime package for ANTLR3
antlr4-python3-runtime     - ANTLR 4.5.2.1 runtime for Python 3.4.0
antlr4-python2-runtime     - ANTLR 4.5.2.1 runtime for Python 2.7.6
  INSTALLED: 4.5.2.1 (latest)

pip install antlr_python_runtime
Collecting antlr-python-runtime
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement antlr-python-runtime (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for antlr-python-runtime
```

`antlr4-python2-runtime` is installed but seems not to be enough:

```
pip install antlr4-python2-runtime
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): antlr4-python2-runtime
```

[This](https://github.com/dsoprea/GDriveFS/issues/88) issue suggests to install with `--allow-unverified` and `--allow-external` but both arguments don't work in the latest version of pip (8.0.2) anymore.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found the 3.1.3 version of antlr in the following [link](http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3.tar.gz)

After running:

```
pip install http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.3.tar.gz
```

the `pip google-appengine` worked ok

Answer (score 1):

pip seems to be stuck on an older 1.5.1 version of AppEngine at and is looking for a bad antrl-python-runtime.
It looks in : https://pypi.python.org/simple/antlr-python-runtime/ which contains no links anymore.

antlr seems to have moved to be called by pip via

```
pip install antlr4_python2_runtime
```

For right now, I think that instead of using pip, brew cask is the best package manager method of obtaining googleappengine 1.9

```
brew cask install googleappengine
```

Comment: brew cask doesn't work on windows, does it? I am using windows and have this issue.

Comment: Also `pip install antlr4-python3-runtime` for Python3.